# put indicator (like a4j:status) on h:commandButton

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

We are using Richfaces 3.3.3.Final. Our problem is about **navigation** problem on **a4j:commandButton**. I know that **navigation** is not working properly  if we use a4j:commandButton (please visit : http://community.jboss.org/wiki/CommonAjaxRequestsProblems#navigation).

Ok I understand that I have to use **h:commandButton** in order to navigation works properly. But now I need an indicator component which will work with h:commandButton. `<a4j:status>` doesn't work with h:commandButton.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<h:commandButton` does not work with `a4j:status` because it does not fire any ajax request - it fires a regular request. And it does not make sense to navigate the browser with ajax.

It appears you want to show work-in-progress when navigating. This is not possible in http in general - you either request a new page and wait for it to come, or make an ajax request.

But you can do another thing - use `<a4j:commandButton oncomplete="redirectBrowser();">`, where `redirectBrowser()` is a javascript function that changes the current url: `window.href.location=/desired/target.jsf'`. It will be triggered when the ajax response comes back. In addition, you can disable the button `onclick`, so that the user does not click it twice.

Comment: i know but i have use h:commandButton in order to work navigation properly. My goal is to prevent system  from double click problem and also gives users a sign that system is in process - because system is gonna calculate lots o things after user clicks that h:commandButton

Comment: @Lurtz - then you shouldn't use `<h:commandButton` - see my update.

Comment: If after click process takes time ~2 minitues then aj4:commandButton doesn't work properly. We see and meausure it. So we can't use aj4:commandButton also richfaces says the same thing -> http://community.jboss.org/wiki/CommonAjaxRequestsProblems#navigation

Comment: @Lurtz - I didn't say to use a4j for navigation. The navigation is done via javascript. And how exactly doesn't a4j:commandButton work? What happens?

Comment: lets seperate your question into two parts.
1 - On firefox : Ajax indicator always running, never ends
2 - On IE8 : First you start -> Ajax indicator works -> operation finishes but navigation doesn't work, page return to itself instead of navigate --> if you push the ajax button again after then navigation works.

Comment: @Lurtz - the 'navigation doesn't work' is this with my suggestion about oncomplete?

Comment: Yes, you indicate a good point but blow javascript function - redirectBrowser() - have not been called. I tried to debug via firebug but no call to redirectBrowser() function. I am investigating.

Comment: Should backbean 's method return type which called from a4j:commandButton is void or String - 
public void startProcess() {
  ... 
}

or 

public String startProcess() {
  return "stockpage.xhtml" 
}

Comment: it works! thanks but i have trivial problem, if an error occurs it still navigate to next page, have can i control that state ? I only want it to navigate on success state.

Comment: @Lurtz - if there is an exception, I think oncomplete should not be triggered. If it is, try to use `onerror` somehow.

Comment: Could you please give an example abour onerror ? oncomplete  always works. Thanks...

Comment: @Lurtz unfortunately I don't have a running project with a4j (I had in the near past), so I can't recall clearly what was it about, and I can't easily experiment. You would have to check the docs and experiment yourself.